# I want to send a push notification IOS, hub azure

Tags: c#, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an azure notification hub built for Android. And I'm building for IOS.

These are the data I need to send in the notification, they are already sent to Android:

```
// Android payload
            JObject data = new JObject();

            data.Add("Id", notification.Id);
            data.Add("Descricao", notification.Descricao);
            data.Add("Tipo", notification.Tipo);
            data.Add("Id_usuario", notification.Id_usuario);
            //data.Add("Informacao", notification.Informacao);
            data.Add("Informacao", notification.Informacao);
            data.Add("Status", notification.Status);
```

How to put this data to push notifications for IOS?

```
var apnsNotification = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + "Some Title"+": " + "\"}}";
```

Comment: have you contacted Apple or any of their API's .. it's going to be a world of difference in IOS we did this using `OutSystems for Android and IOS` and IOS is a POS when it comes to cross platform development on mobile devices

Comment: But in theory, by azure doc, it would only be me to send the json in the correct format. In theory, the rest is built. This part of how to send correctly, this json custom, which I have not got yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method works for me:

```
public static async void sendPushNotificationApns(ApiController controller, DataObjects.Notification notification)
{
    // Get the settings for the server project.
    HttpConfiguration config = controller.Configuration;

    MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings =
        controller.Configuration.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();

    // Get the Notification Hubs credentials for the Mobile App.
    string notificationHubName = settings.NotificationHubName;
    string notificationHubConnection = settings
        .Connections[MobileAppSettingsKeys.NotificationHubConnectionString].ConnectionString;

    // Create a new Notification Hub client.
    NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(notificationHubConnection, notificationHubName);

    var apnsNotification = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + notification.Descricao + "\"},\"Id\":\"" + notification.Id +
        "\",\"Tipo\":\"" + notification.Tipo + "\",\"Id_usuario\":\"" + notification.Id_usuario +
        "\",\"Informacao\":\"" + notification.Informacao +
        "\",\"Status\":\"" + notification.Status + "\"}";

    try
    {
        // Send the push notification and log the results.
        String tag = "_UserId:" + notification.Id_usuario;               
        var result = await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(apnsNotification, tag);

        // Write the success result to the logs.
        config.Services.GetTraceWriter().Info(result.State.ToString());
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        // Write the failure result to the logs.
        config.Services.GetTraceWriter().Error(ex.Message, null, "Push.SendAsync Error");
    }
}
```